# Haxe swc output, Is it possible to leave comments?

Tags: haxe, swc

When I compile swc, haxe compiler removes all comments. I suppose there should be some compiler parameter, but I can't find any.

Comment: For what reason would you do it? Comments are made to stay in source files! From what i know there is no compiler in the world that consider in any way the comments

Comment: I want to get something similar to this:
http://screencast.com/t/tjcqawqS

At the moment I'm trying to make work Asdoc with haxe, and then add xml files with comments to swc.

Comment: To clarify: You tried to create an SWC file with Haxe that includes ASDOC generated XML file(s) that help with auto completition, right? You might want to describe what you already have tried - and into what actual problems ("what did I expect? what happened instead?") you have run into. With such a vague description you won't be able to get help.

Answer (score 0):

No, compiler removes (ignores) comments automatically. As for Asdocs, if you have commented correctly your code those should appear highlighted in any IDE that supports it like FB 4.7 for example.